# JAVA -> GWT -> JS double value comparison

Tags: java, gwt, double

I've some trouble comparing two double.

If I use the values as they came I have a weird behaviour (if a > b a comparison give b < a !!).

'report' is a class created by GWT rpc

```
double A = report.getR_press_delta_pressure();
double B = report.getR_press_0_delta();

Window.alert("compare("+A+", "+B+") = "+Double.compare(A, B));
```

> compare(50.0,200.0) = 1

```
A = 50.0;
B = 200.0;
Window.alert("compare("+A+", "+B+") = "+Double.compare(A, B));
```

> compare(50.0,200.0) = -1 (OK)

```
A = Double.parseDouble(""+report.getR_press_delta_pressure());
B = Double.parseDouble(""+report.getR_press_0_delta());
Window.alert("compare("+A+", "+B+") = "+Double.compare(A, B));
```

> compare(50.0,200.0) = -1  (OK)

I obtain the same error with classic comparison ">", "<"

There is a reason for this?
Am I doing something wrong?

The get() methods are automatically generated:

```
public final native double getR_press_delta_pressure() /*-{
    return this.r_press_delta_pressure;
}-*/;

public final native double getR_press_0_delta() /*-{
    return this.r_press_0_delta;
}-*/;
```

The code is permuted by GWT from Java to HTML + JS, so the final functions are JS

Comment: Can you show the code for the `get()` methods?

Comment: The get() methods are automatically generated:

Comment: I'm not awake. I thought it was the plus signs, but they're used to append the strings. Is the compiler taking +Double.compare(A, B) as make it positive?? I'll try it with java 1.8

Comment: Interesting problem. The methods have to be returning 50.0 and 200.0. That's what they're printing  What version of GWT?

Comment: GWT version 2.7.0

Comment: Where is the "(OK)" coming from? Is it actually in the output? If so, is there any chance that r_press_0_delta is actually a string, and not a double in the raw JS? GWT JSNI methods do not check the type when they return a value, it is assumed that your JS is valid and has correct types (insofar as JS has types...).

Comment: `The code is permuted by GWT from Java to HTML + JS, so the final functions are JS` yes, the _final_ functions are JS but your `getWhatever()` methods in Java should not be native JS methods. The **whole** point of GWT is so you don't need to even _see_ JS code, let alone write it, ever. Back to your question, the use of `this` in JSNI is a bit tricky: `this` in Java is not the same as `this` in JS. What kind of object is `report`?

Comment: Actually, @ColinAlworth comment makes sense. Interpreted as strings, `"50.0"` is "bigger" than `"200.0"`. Only when you parse them as Doubles or enter them manually, is `50.0` lower than `200.0`. Are you sure the code you're showing us, is the same code you're actually running??

Comment: I have put the (OK) to specify that is the right behaviour.

Comment: @willygroup There are reasons to think that the code you're showing in the first block is not the real code. Maybe you altered it for better clarity and in doing so, you (unknowingly) hid the problem from us. Please make sure the code is exactly the same, else we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I've solved:
in the php file I retrieve the values from a sqlite db, here I need to specify that the value is a float, like this:

```
$result->r_press_0_delta = floatval($row['r_press_0_delta']);
$result->press_delta_pressure = floatval($row['press_delta_pressure']);
```

Thank you all.